# Google analytics thinks redirect URL is the referral

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, referrals

I have a couple of questions to do with how Google Analytics tracks traffic to my Wordpress site.
When I check the "referrals" on my console, I see that my old domain name (let's call it `old.com` ) is at the top of the referrals. I have the Domain setting of the `old.com` to point to my site (say new.com). However, the old domain hasn't been used for a long time anywhere to the best of my knowledge.
My questions are:

- How can I find out why there is traffic through the `old.com` domain?
- How can I track the original referrals that go to through `old.com` ?

Thanks in advance!

Vedat

Comment: If this is a serverside redirect then it should not show up as referral. So the first thing to check would be how your webhost handles redirection.

Answer (score 0):

When you change domain, you have to set up the 301 redirect or you may have problems with Analytics and SEO.

https://moz.com/blog/seo-guide-how-to-properly-move-domains

Comment: Thanks Nick. My site is actually doing OK in the SEO. What I don't understand is, how come this very old URL is getting triggered as the source of most traffic. Is it because both the old and new URL's directories are the same, and somehow the analytics is looking at that regardless of how the traffic is generated? Should I give the old URL its own directory and place a 301 redirect to the current URL? Will this make more problems at this stage?Thank you!

Comment: Without an analysis of the url it is difficult to answer you :) I can only say that the old url needs to be properly addressed to new ones. If you did all right you should not have any problems.

Comment: Thanks. I went ahead and moved the domain name to its own directory, and placed an .htaccess file with a 301 redirect to the new domain. It's been almost 24hrs and it seems to be working fine. We'll see if I keep on seeing the redirect as referrals in analytics. Cheers!